# Evaluate $\int_0^t\exp\left[- \frac{a(\delta+1)(t-x)}{(\delta-(t-x))}\right] \, b\exp[-bx] dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, continuity

I cannot find a closed form solution for the following integral:
$$\int_0^t\exp\left[- \frac{a(\delta+1)(t-x)}{(\delta-(t-x))}\right] \, b\exp[-bx] dx$$
So, to evaluate this integral, I have used numerical integration (in Matlab). Note that $a$, $b$, $\delta$ and $t$ are all positive. When I set $\delta<t$ the result is infinity. However, if $t=\delta$ the result is not infinity; ex: $a=0.1$, $b=1$, and $t=4$.

I suspect that the problem results from the denominator $\delta-(t-x)$, which is equal to $0$ if $x= t-\delta$.

My question: does the above mean that the integral diverges and goes to infinity for $\delta <t$ ? or it is the numerical approach used that is not good in this case? if so, is there any other approach to compute the integral ?

Comment: what is the meaning of this brackets $$[...]$$?

Comment: $\exp[..]$ is equivalent to $\exp(..)$. Maybe it is a bad choice to use this notation. Please feel free to edit the question.

Comment: can you say something about the parameters?

Comment: This is not an integral unless you decide something for $d$, say $dx$?

Comment: Thank you for pointing out this issue. I have edited the question.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  As indicated in the question, these parameters are all positive. $\delta$ can take values such that $\delta \ge t$ and also $\delta <t$. Please note that you can use the example I have provided in the question: $a=0.1$, $b=1$, $t=4$, and suppose I want to evaluate the integral for $\delta=2$ and $\delta=5$.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing to do is to change variables $t-x=tz$, yielding
$$
I=\int_0^t\exp\left[- \frac{a(\delta+1)(t-x)}{(\delta-(t-x))}\right] \, b\exp[-bx]dx=bt e^{-bt}\int_0^1 dz \exp\left[- \frac{a(\delta+1)tz}{\delta-tz}\right] e^{btz}
$$
$$
\propto \int_0^1 dz \exp\left[- \frac{Az}{B-z}\right] e^{Cz}\ ,
$$
where $A$, $B$ and $C$ are the only combinations of parameters that are really relevant. Now, if $0<B<1$, the integrand has a one-sided divergence as $z\to B$ (essential singularity) *inside the integration range* which is non-integrable. As $B=\delta/t$, you have your answer. If $B$ is exactly equal to one, the integral is perfectly fine as 
$$
\lim_{z\to 1^-} \exp\left[-\frac{Az}{1-z}\right]=0\ ,
$$
so there are no divergences inside the integration range.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand your answer, for $\delta < t$ having $I$ equals to infinity is normal, meaning that the integral diverges if $\delta < t$, ?

Comment: Yes, that's correct